# How to split a phrase into words in pascal?

Tags: split, pascal, procedure, phrase

I have to create a program that splits phrases (with special characters such as % and $) into words using a procedure in pascal.

So if i enter:

```
This is a valid word: 12$%ab
```

The program must return me:

```
This
is
a
valid
word:
12$#ab
```

Without the spaces, one below the other.

I can't use arrays and the variable that "calls" the procedure must be a string.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
program words;
uses crt;
var 
 phrase  :string;
 word:string;
 letter  :char;
 x      :integer;

begin
 clrscr;
 phrase:='';
 word:='';
 x:=1;                         
 repeat
  write('type a phrase: ');
  readln(phrase);
  until phrase<>'';
 while x<=length(phrase) do
 begin
  letter:=phrase[x];
  case letter of
   'a'..'z','A'..'Z':
    begin
     word:=word+letter;
     repeat
       x:=x+1;
       letter:=phrase[x];
       word:=word+letter;
      until (letter=' ') or (x=length(phrase));
     writeln(word);
     word:='';
    end;
  end;
  x:=x+1;
 end;
writeln;
readkey;
end.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working for you? This isn't a "please do my homework for me" or "please write my code for me" site. You need to try and figure it out yourself, post the code you've tried that isn't working, and describe the problem you're having with that code, and someone can try and help you get it working. You need to show some effort yourself first, though. Good luck.

Comment: I could make it work without the procedure.

Comment: How do i enter code here in the comments?

Comment: You add the code like you did above; by editing the question. There's help available for formatting (click the `?` icon above the top right of the text area where you enter your question text). You need to **post the code you've tried**, not just reformat the question. No one here is going to do your homework for you (and if they do, they'll probably get downvoted or have their answers deleted). **Do your own work**, and post the **code** that isn't working for you.

Comment: Never meant for nobody to do my homework, it's just that i'm new to this and i need a little help.

Comment: Well, you're closer. :-) What is the issue you're having with the code you posted? You've now described the assignment and shown your effort, but you failed to say what problem you're having. In what way is the code you posted not working the way you'd expect? (You can just make a procedure out of the code after your `readln` loop (just before your `while` statement), and pass what you got in the `readln` into it as a parameter, if that helps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what the problem is with the code provided (although it will fail should there be a digit in the given string), but I can see that it is inefficient - there's no need for all the string concatenation. I can see two other ways of handling the problem -

first approach - search, print and delete

```
repeat
 write ('type a phrase: ');
 readln (phrase);
until phrase <>'';

while phrase <> '' do
 begin
  i:= pos (' ', phrase);
  if i = 0 then
   begin
    writeln (phrase);
    phrase:= ''
   end
  else
   begin
    writeln (copy (phrase, 1, i-1));  // no need to write the terminating space!   
    phrase:= copy (phrase, i + 1, length (phrase) - i)
   end
 end;
```

second approach: search, print and continue

```
repeat
 write ('type a phrase: ');
 readln (phrase);
until phrase <>'';

j:= 1;
i:= 1;
len:= length (phrase);
repeat
 while (phrase[i] <> ' ') and (i < len) do inc (i);
 writeln (copy (phrase, j, i - 1));
 j:= i;
 inc (i)
until i > len;
```

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them. Just point them in the direction of figuring it out themselves. By giving the answer, all they're learning is how to copy and paste code that they don't understand. The teachers give assignments for a reason - so that the student learns something by figuring out how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot No'am Newman for showing me other ways to do it. Rest assured that i won't simply copy and paste, i rather rewrite myself and i'll take this as a lesson.
Ken, i have the worst teacher ever. He was supposed to assign this work 2 weeks ago and instead he assigned monday due to wednsday (today!) He shows up late, when he attends class he doesn't come up with a class plan and rarely corrects anything. I'm practically learning by myself. So anything you guys do to help me I'll take as lesson.
Sorry for the broken english, it's not my native language. And yeah, i taught myself that too.

Comment: @user1840579: The second version is more of a standard Pascal approach, although I notice that a 'copy' crept in. Your exercise is to rewrite the code *without* the copy - which means that you will have to change the 'while' loop as well.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each character for the length of the string, check if it's a space, if it is, print the previous characters, if not, add to a variable containing previous characters.